# Need to force realization of lazy seqs before/after element-wise imperative operations?

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

If I perform a side-effecting/mutating operation on individual data structures specific to each member of lazy sequence using `map`, do I need to (a) call `doall` first, to force realization of the original sequence before performing the imperative operations, or (b) call `doall` to force the side-effects to occur before I map a functional operation over the resulting sequence?

I believe that no `doall`s are necessary when there are no dependencies *between* elements of any sequence, since `map` can't apply a function to a member of a sequence until the functions from `map`s that produced that sequence have been applied to the corresponding element of the earlier sequence.  Thus, *for each element*, the functions will be applied in the proper sequence, even though one of the functions produces side effects that a later function depends on.  (I know that I can't assume that any element *a* will have been modified before element *b* is, but that doesn't matter.)

Is this correct?

That's the question, and if it's sufficiently clear, then there's no need to read further. The rest describes what I'm trying to do in more detail.

---

My application has a sequence of defrecord structures ("agents") each of which contains some core.matrix vectors (`vec1`, `vec2`) and a core.matrix matrix (`mat`).  Suppose that for the sake of speed, I decide to (destructively, not functionally) modify the matrix.

The program performs the following three steps to each of the agents by calling `map`, three times, to apply each step to each agent.

1. Update a vector `vec1` in each agent, functionally, using `assoc`.
2. Modify a matrix `mat` in each agent based on the preceding vector (i.e. the matrix will retain a different state).
3. Update a vector `vec2` in each agent using `assoc` based on the state of the matrix produced by    step 2.

For example, where `persons` is a sequence, possibly lazy (EDIT: Added outer `doall`s):

```
(doall
  (->> persons
    (map #(assoc % :vec1 (calc-vec1 %)))            ; update vec1 from person
    (map update-mat-from-vec1!)                     ; modify mat based on state of vec1
    (map #(assoc % :vec2 (calc-vec2-from-mat %))))) ; update vec2 based on state of mat
```

Alternatively:

```
(doall
  (map #(assoc % :vec2 (calc-vec2-from-mat %))     ; update vec2 based on state of mat
       (map update-mat-from-vec1!                  ; modify mat based on state of vec1
            (map #(assoc % :vec1 (calc-vec1 %)) persons)))) ; update vec1 from person
```

Note that no agent's state depends on the state of any *other* agent at any point.  Do I need to add `doall`s?

---

EDIT: **Overview of answers as of 4/16/2014:**

I recommend reading all of the answers given, but it may seem as if they conflict.  They don't, and I thought it might be useful if I summarized the main ideas:

(1) The answer to my question is "Yes": If, at the end of the process I described, one causes the entire lazy sequence to be realized, then what is done to each element will occur according to the correct sequence of steps (1, 2, 3).  There is no need to apply `doall` before or after step 2, in which each element's data structure is mutated.

(2) But: This is a very bad idea; you are asking for trouble in the future.  If at some point you inadvertently end up realizing all or part of the sequence at a time other than what you originally intended, it could turn out that the later steps get values from the data structure that were put there at at the wrong time--at a time other than what you expect. The step that mutates a per-element data structure won't happen until a given element of the lazy seq is realized, so if you realize it at the wrong time, you could get the wrong data in later steps.  This could be the kind of bug that is very difficult to track down.  (Thanks to @A.Webb for making this problem very clear.)

Comment: I take it that by "imperative" you mean "with side effects" judging by the "!"s in your examples.

Comment: Yes, I thought about using that term.  Is 'imperative' not specific enough?  I can change it.

Comment: I would specify "side effects". Since some of the answers you received do not address side effects at all, I think that aspect of your question was lost.

Comment: A that maybe ought be followed up, if at all, in meta: I think there's some tension between trying to provide brief, clear questions, and trying to head off answers that don't address the question directly, but in essence say "Don't do that" or "Don't forget to do what you didn't mention."  Since Clojure departs from the mainstream, programmers naturally, and helpfully, want to redirect people from practices common in other languages but that *often* are a bad idea in Clojure.  This makes it hard to ask questions succinctly without adding qualifications explaining that you know that already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *extreme caution* mixing laziness with side effects

```
(defrecord Foo [fizz bang])

(def foos (map ->Foo (repeat 5 0) (map atom (repeat 5 1))))

(def foobars (map #(assoc % :fizz @(:bang %)) foos))
```

So will my fizz of foobars now be 1?

```
(:fizz (first foobars)) ;=> 1
```

Cool, now I'll leave foobars alone and work with my original foos...

```
(doseq [foo foos] (swap! (:bang foo) (constantly 42)))
```

Let's check on foobars

```
(:fizz (first foobars)) ;=> 1
(:fizz (second foobars)) ;=> 42
```

Whoops...

Generally, use `doseq` instead of `map` for your side effects or be aware of the consequences of delaying your side effects until realization.

Comment: Extreme caution: Yes, that's why I asked.  Nice example.

Comment: @Mars I hope this example shows you how your computations can get out of order when both side effects and laziness are involved.

Comment: It sounds like you want me to avoid mixing them, but I have a good reason to consider imperatively modifying matrices.  I don't fully understand the example yet.  It convinces me to be *more* careful with atoms than I would be with some other imperative effects.  Why does `:fizz` end up with `:bang`'s deref'ed value when the `swap!` modifies `:bang`?  In the `assoc` call, doesn't the `@` extract the value itself, and stick that into `:fizz`?

Comment: There are good reasons for mutating ("imperatively modifying"). The problem is when the order of your mutations is not properly enforced because some are pending the realization of a lazy sequence. The use of atoms here is for ease of example, the same could be done for any mutation of state, including matrices.

Comment: @Mars applying this lesson to your example above - if you held on to the `persons` value that was input to your operation and looked at the matrices referenced by it, the observed value would be different based on whether the result of your operation had been realized or not. Depending on the logic of your program, that could be a subtle source of bugs.

Comment: A. Webb, are you disagreeing with @LeonidBeschastny's and @ArthurUlfeldt's answers?  Is the lesson that I don't need to call `doall` between steps only *as long as I don't realize any part of the sequences*?  i.e. realization has to be all or nothing, or there could be trouble.

Comment: @Alex, ah, I get it.  Makes sense.  But that should not be a problem for me.

Comment: It's not that I'm disagreeing with them, its (1) they possibly don't realize you are mutating elements or (2) none of us know how you are using this at large. @Alex points out what I was trying to hint at, you are possibly setting yourself up for some very subtle bugs down the line by mixing laziness with side effects.

Comment: I think I see what you're worried about (on my behalf!). The point of the mutated matrices in the agents is really just to feed into the next step.  `doseq` or wrapping `doall` would work, too.  Then there are other steps, and then it starts over on result of it all.  I would `doall` anything before asking for output to a user, and before doing anything in which different agents depend on each other.  I have to be careful when debugging, though--e.g. inserted print statements might require forcing realization early.

Comment: Now that I have had more time to play with your example, A. Webb, I understand much better: In `foobars`, `:fizz` is getting the contents of `:bang` at the time that each element of the sequence is realized.  Great illustration of evils that await me when I'm not paying attention.  And I understand why it's consistent with the other answers.  Sorry for not taking more time before commenting.  I will use `doseq` or wrap `doall` directly around side-effecting code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add any calls to `doall` provided you do something with the results later in your program. For instance if you ran the above maps, and did nothing with the result then none of the elements will be realized. On the other hand, if you read through the resulting sequence, to print it for instance, then **each of your computations will happen in order on each element sequentially.** That is steps 1, 2, and 3 will happen to the first thing in the input sequence, then steps 1, 2, and 3 will happen to the second and so forth. There is no need to pre-realize sequences to ensure the values are available, lazy evaluation will take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add `doall` between two `map` operations. But unless you're working in a REPL, you do need to add `doall` or `dorun` to force the execution of your lazy sequence.

This is true, unless you care about the order of operations.

Let's consider the following example:

```
(defn f1 [x]
  (print "1>" x ", ")
  x)

(defn f2 [x]
  (print "2>" x ", ")
  x)

(defn foo [mycoll]
  (->> mycoll
    (map f1)
    (map f2)
    dorun))
```

By default clojure will take the first chunk of `mycoll` and apply `f1` to all elements of this chunk. Then it'll apply `f2` to the resulting chunk.

So, if `mycoll` if a `list` or an ordinary lazy sequence, you'll see that `f1` and `f2` are applied to each element in turn:

```
=> (foo (list \a \b))
1> a , 2> a , 1> b , 2> b , nil
```

or

```
=> (->> (iterate inc 7) (take 2) foo)
1> 7 , 2> 7 , 1> 8 , 2> 8 , nil
```

But if `mycoll` is a `vector` or chunked lazy sequence, you'll see quite a different thing:

```
=> (foo [\a \b])
1> a , 1> b , 2> a , 2> b , nil
```

Try

```
=> (foo (range 50))
```

and you'll see that it processes elements in chunks by 32 elements.

So, **be careful using lazy calculations with side effects**!

Here are some hints for you:

Always end you command with `doall` or `dorun` to force the calculation.

Use `doall` and `comp` to control the order of calculations, e.g.:

```
(->> [\a \b]
  ; apply both f1 and f2 before moving to the next element
  (map (comp f2 f1))
  dorun)

(->> (list \a \b)
  (map f1)
  ; process the whole sequence before applying f2
  doall
  (map f2)
  dorun)
```

Comment: Hint 3: test with seqs longer than 32 so you don't get fooled by the chunking behavior of map.

Answer (score 0):

`map` always produces a lazy result, even for a non-lazy input. You should call `doall` (or `dorun` if the sequence will never be used and the mapping is only done for side effects) on the output of `map` if you need to force some imperative side effect (for example use a file handle or db connection before it is closed).

```
user> (do (map println [0 1 2 3]) nil)
nil
user> (do (doall (map println [0 1 2 3])) nil)
0
1
2
3
nil
```

Comment: Thanks noisesmith.  Yes, I assumed that.