# Convert a list with to distinct regions into a Map

Tags: clojure, idioms

Convert a list of this form:

```
 ( arg1  arg2 ... :first_keyword val_1 :key2 val_2 ... )
```

Into this map:

```
 { 1 arg1, 2 arg2, ..., :first_keyword val_1, :key2 val_2, ... }
```

I can see very ugly ways to do this.  But what is the Clojure way to do this?

```
  .
  .
  .
```

(P.S. My early reaction to Clojure is that it feels a little like it is
      optimized for more "toy-like" tasks.  if the logic connecting your inputs
      and outputs has any hair on it, then it feels to me I am spending more 
      effort fighting the language rather than the problem.  specifically,
      keeping track of the fifth argument in your 'recurs' statement feels
      like I am doing something the compiler should be doing... 
      but perhaps my Clojure vision is still too weak...)

Comment: I don't think Clojure is at all toy-like.  It's different.  Functional programming requires a shift in thinking, and learning to use the conveniences that Clojure has available takes some getting used to.  But me saying that is no reason for you to agree.  You may find that even with experience it's not comfortable.  I don't think Clojure is ideal for everyone, nor is it ideal for every task.  (I do think Clojure is "toy-like" in this sense:  imo, it makes a lot of things much easier--and fun--than in, say, Java.  That makes Java feel more "serious"--but not better.  Others will disagree.)

Comment: Its not that Closure seems toy like, but rather the problems it can solve elegantly seem potentially limited.  One can always create a loop with all of your local variables in it, and then a massive recurs statement to update all your locals, but this feels like we are saddling the programmer w. needless complexity.  Closure has hundreds of very specially shaped methods like split-with to try to avoid this, but it starts to feel like trying to write a news article in haiku.    (of course if you can do it, well I guess it does prove your brilliance!)  Anyway Thanks!

Comment: "problems it can solve elegantly seem potentially limited": Perhaps that's true, for the kind of problems that are salient for you, and for your sense of elegance--or perhaps with more experience you would change your mind.   Who knows?   Others surely disagree.  I have no such feeling about Clojure.  I regret I can't do all my coding in Clojure. I do think that purely functional, side-effect free programming has disadvantages as well as advantages, and using side-effects in Clojure requires extra coding (atoms, etc.) or extra care.  I don't need side-effects as much as I'd thought, though.

Comment: Regarding your P.S. ... put the problems which *cause you to spend more effort fighting the language than the problem* as questions and see what answers you get. Who knows. You may be right. But I have to say that my experience is quite the opposite.

Comment: @thumbnail, I love homoiconic languages, and I am swayed that functional "superstructure" is worth the constraint.  But making mutable local variables such an eyesore and pain (and non-performant) seems a great loss.  It seems there are 100 different loopy to help me program w/o local variables in a for loop.  For this one decision specifically I dont see the saving in complexity, speed, safety, etc.    (I would love to issue my PS as a question, but StackOverflow does not like those sorts of questions.)  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Dan, it's still not clear to me whether you might be thinking about how to implement an algorithms in Clojure that are better for a non-functional language, when there are equally good algorithms that would work better in a functional language.  I don't see why *as a general rule*, altering local variables by assignment is simpler/cleaner/more elegant than "changing" variables by passing new values of them via `recur` or even true recursion.  To every thing there is a place, though.  I do think that sometimes assignment can be clearer; when that's what you need, perhaps Clojure is suboptimal.

Comment: @mars we are in agreement. I just imagine a Clojure++ that is consistent w. clojure and has parsimonious, performant, mutables locals. Such a SINGLE language would be optimal for both cases. I expect Rich knew this, but opted against it as many programmers might overly rely on these locals. If I get bored, I might even create a macro that translates "+var+" symbols into var-sets and derefs as appropriate in order to use them as locals in a visually pleasant way. I wonder if such a macro would be a Clojure "sin" of sorts?  (grin)

Comment: I'm not without sympathy toward your feelings.  I'm not sure that the awkwardness of assignment in Clojure was done purely to make it uncomfortable, though that may be a factor. L aziness has minuses as well as plusses, but it really can get very tricky when you start throwing in side effects.  Everybody needs 'em, but casual use of assignment can lead to confusion.  [This answer by A. Webb](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23066351/1455243) helped to convince me of this point.  I routinely use assignment with clojure.core.matrix to avoid copying an entire matrix, but in a very controlled way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
(let [[vals keyvals]
      (split-with (complement keyword?) 
                  [100 101 102 :a 103 :b 104 :c 105])]
  (merge (zipmap (range) vals) 
         (apply hash-map keyvals)))

=> {:a 103, :b 104, :c 105, 2 102, 1 101, 0 100}
```

That makes 0 the key of the first element.  If you want 1-based keys, you could wrap `(range)` in `(map inc _)`.

Other notes:

`(split-with (complement keyword?) ...)` splits the sequence into two parts: a sequence with no keywords, and the rest.

`(zipmap (range) vals)` "zips" the two sequences together into a map, using as many integers from `range` as there are `vals`.

Comment: To start at `1`, use `(rest (range))`.

Comment: Ah, much better.  Thanks @Thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

```
(loop [inputs ["arg1" "arg2" :key1 1 :key2 2] index 1 output {}]
  (if (empty? inputs) output
    (let [input (first inputs) rest-inputs (rest inputs)]
      (if (keyword? input)
        (recur (rest rest-inputs) index (assoc output input (second inputs)))
        (recur rest-inputs (inc index) (assoc output index input))))))
```

You could maybe use a `for` comprehension or `reduce` with some pre-processing but a loop may be cleanest in this case.

Comment: Thanks Optevo, I think my problem spec was ambiguous.  the goal was to treat all pairs after the first keyword as key/value pairs.  I think your code will still allow fixed args after the first keyword.  but I dont think I was so claer.