# What are side-effects in predicates and why are they bad?

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

I'm wondering what is considered to be a side-effect in predicates for `fn`s like `remove` or `filter`. There seems to be a range of possibilities. Clearly, if the predicate writes to a file, this is a side-effect. But consider a situation like this:

```
(def *big-var-that-might-be-garbage-collected* ...)

(let [my-ref *big-var-that-might-be-garbage-collected*]
  (defn my-pred
    [x]
    (some-operation-on my-ref x)))
```

Even if `some-operation-on` is merely a query that does not change state, the fact that `my-pred` retains a reference to `*big...` changes the state of the system in that the big var cannot be garbage collected. Is this also considered to be side-effect?

In my case, I'd like to write to a logging system in a predicate. Is this a side effect?

And why are side-effects in predicates discouraged exactly? Is it because `filter` and `remove` and their friends work lazily so that you cannot determine when the predicates are called (and - hence - when the side-effects happen)?

Comment: Wouldn't `my-ref` become aother reference to the same object as `*big...` so that it may never be garbage collected as long as  `my-pred` exists?

Comment: Exactly this is my point. I was looking for an example of a 'subtle' side-effect.

Comment: The answers below provide links to further information. Any book or web introduction on Clojure or Haskell will discuss the dangers of side-effects, as well.  Side effects are especially problematic in Clojure and Haskell because they use lazy evaluation in many situations.  It was [this answer by A. Webb](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23066351/1455243) that really opened my eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GC is not typically considered when evaluating if a function is pure or not, although many actions that make a function impure can have a GC effect.

Logging is a side effect, as is changing any state in the program or the world. A pure function takes data and returns data, without modifying anything else.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15269/why-are-side-effects-considered-evil-in-functional-programming covers why side effects are avoided in functional languages.

Answer (score 0):

[I found this link helpful](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/clojure/119vg3v6p0/iterate-with-side-effect-function)

The problem is determining when, or even whether, the side-effects will occur on any given call to the function.

If you only care that the same inputs return the same answer, you are fine. Side-effects are dependent on *how* the function is executed.

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
(first (filter odd? (range 20)))
; 1
```

But if we arrange for `odd?` to print its argument as it goes:

```
(first (filter #(do (print %) (odd? %)) (range 20)))
```

It will print `012345678910111213141516171819` before returning `1`!

The reason is that `filter`, where it can, deals with its sequence argument in *chunks* of 32 elements.

If we take the limit off the `range`:

```
(first (filter #(do (print %) (odd? %)) (range)))
```

... we get a full-size chunk printed: `012345678910111213141516171819012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031`

Just printing the argument is confusing. If the side effects are significant, things could go seriously awry.